# Integrate $ I=\int_0^1 dx\ln\bigg(\frac{A}{A-x(1-x)B}\bigg) $

Tags: calculus, integration, quantum-field-theory

I am currently working on a mathematical problem in QFT when I came across the integral:
$$
I=\int_0^1 dx\ln\bigg(\frac{A}{A-x(1-x)B}\bigg)
$$
I have no idea how to do such an integral, or where to even start. I am assuming that it will be a contour integral and I will need a branch cut, but that's it.

More info in the physics part: I am working on using Pauli-Villars regularization of a single loop correction to the $\phi^4$ theory.

I got stuck when I used Feynman reparametrization and then ended up with this integral.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't give me an elementary antiderivative. I forgot the part that A and B are positives. From what I could gather, this should end up with $log\big(\frac{A}{B}\big)$ but it doesn't give me that answer.

Comment: hmm I also forgot the part that the denominator is actually $A-x(1-x)B+i\epsilon$ for some  small $\epsilon$. I don't know if that changes everything as it is only going to be written with that for divergent integrals, but the final answer doesn't seem to correspond to the answer they have.

Comment: According to Mathematica your integral $I$ evaluates to $$I=2-\frac{2 \sqrt{4 A-B} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{4 A-B}}\right)}{\sqrt{B}}$$

Comment: hmm, yes so weird. I'm just going to not learn Paulis-Villars regularization and just skip to dimensional regularization lol. I have no idea how they evaluated their integral to end up with $log\frac{A}{B}$.